# как с помощью js получить значение из radio checkbox

Tags: javascript

Я только учусь, подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить значения из `<input type="radio" />`, в `input`'e типа `text` одно поле, а у `radio` - два, и как получить значение чекбокса не могу понять.

```js
$(function() {
  // Кнопка сохранить
  $(".save").click(function() {
    var A = $(this).parent().parent();
    var X = A.attr("id");
    var d = X.split("formbox"); // Определяем id : formbox
    var id = d[1];
    var Z = $("#" + X + " input.name").val();
    var S = $("#" + X + " input.am").val();
    var I = $("#" + X + " input.tp").val(); //Вот тут я похоже
    var Y = $("#" + X + " input.noind").val(); //не правильно получаю данные
    console.log("var S " + S); //Ok
    console.log("var Z " + Z); //Ok
    console.log("var Y " + Y); //Undefined
    console.log("var I " + I); //Undefined
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form811">
  <label for="name">Название</label>
  <input id="name811" type="text" value="" name="name" class="name" />

  <label for="am">Сумма</label>
  <input type="text" value="0" name="am" class="am" />

  <span class="label">Индекс:</span>
  <input id="index811" type="radio" name="noind" value="0" checked="checked" />
  <label for="index811">index</label>
  <input id="noindex811" type="radio" name="noind" value="1" />
  <label for="noindex811">no index</label>

  <span class="label">Тип:</span>
  <input id="photo811" type="radio" name="tp" value="0" checked="checked" />
  <label for="photo811">фото</label>
  <input id="price811" type="radio" name="tp" value="1" />
  <label for="price811">для прайса</label>

  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="alt_edit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил вот так

```
var Y = $("input[name=noind]:checked").val();
var I = $("input[name=tp]:checked").val();
```